# Element API User example

Tags: plugin-elementapi, json

I am attempting to build an application where Craft handles all of the API based data (JSON). I am using the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI). I can't find an example anywhere online that outputs Users.

I am trying to output some basics first before I start outputting the custom Matrix fields etc. Here is my `elementapi.json`:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'players.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'User',
            'criteria' => ['group' => 'player'],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry){
                return [
                    'username' => $entry->$username,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("player/{$entry->id}.json")
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Any help or an example with some custom matrix user fields would be much appreciated! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for editing there, sorry I left the namespace out, that is actually *is* in my elementapi.php . I am just getting a blank page at the moment when I reference mysite.dev.com/players.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `elementType` to `User`, then the transformer will have a [`UserModel`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel) object passed in like so:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'players.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'User',
            'criteria' => ['group' => 'player'],
            'transformer' => function(\Craft\UserModel $user) {
                return [
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("player/{$user->id}.json")
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Brad: I get this:

Property "Craft\UserModel." is not defined.

Comment: Did you get that error before or after my edit?

Comment: Hi Brad, no all good, thanks a bunch for the help! It would be really helpful to see a full example with specific user profiles JSON like the entries is layed out :) Thanks again!